# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation translate to a point rather then by a value.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

My question is simple.

Let us say I use this method

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5.0f, 0.0f);
```

which translates the image view 5 pixels to the right. But is there a similar method that does the exact same thing except takes the destination point as an argument rather then the values you want to move the image view by?

For example, if I wanted to move an image view to 100.0f, 0.0f what would I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following two options:

```
imgOne.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
```

or

```
imgOne.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, imgOne.frame.size.width, imgOne.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the center point you want to move to this coordinate, use:

```
imageView.center = CGPointMake(100.0f, 0.0f);
```

If it's one of the corner points, subtract/add half the view's frame's width/height to the coordinates. If you need this frequently, it's a good idea to write a small `UIView` category that allows you to position a view's corner on a particular coordinate.